# Is there a good phrase to replace "camera-shy" within the context of long-form podcasting?

Tags: phrase-requests

Yes, I'll admit it; I've watched a fair number of Joe Rogan podcasts. Now, I have a need to describe a specific condition I've seen in these 'casts a number of times. The condition is where the guest is obviously intimidated by the headphones and microphone. Mr Rogan is forever encouraging guests to get the microphone right in their faces.

Many guests exhibit a clear discomfort with the equipment. It is this discomfort I am trying to capture. I'm searching for a phrase I can use multiple times in a business plan without sounding tiresome.

There are not only headphones and microphones to be intimidated by; there are also cameras in the studio. However, as these aren't in such close contact with the guest, they seem to cause less frequent bouts of anxiety or self-consciousness. Yet, the term I'm looking for would also encapsulate that occasional angst as well.

Comment: I think it's just generically being shy. I worked recording people for some time and I don't recall there being a specific term.

Comment: Google shows "mic/microphone shyness" is a term some people use, but I can't tell you any more than that.

Comment: **Stage fright**. It’s an old term but still applicable.

Comment: @GlobalCharm: _Stage fright_ - yeah, I like it. That covers the bases and it's familiar enough to be comfortable in speech.

Comment: FYI--He often has to remind people to stay on the mic because people aren't accustomed to positioning themselves. From what I've heard, it's not always stage fright, although that gets at what you're asking. It's just a skill people haven't learned yet.